# OpenSSL C API - getting keylength of public key in DER encoding

Tags: c, openssl, public-key

I would like to determine the key length of a public key encoded in `DER` format while using the `OpenSSL` API in `C`.

It is quite straight-forward to do this with a key encoded in `PEM` format:

```
FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
RSA *rsa_key = PEM_read_RSA_PUBKEY(fp, NULL, NULL, NULL);
int keylength = RSA_size(rsa_key);
```

(assuming that the key to be loaded has been passed as an argument)

Unfortunately there is no equivalent `DER_read_RSA_PUBKEY` function.
I have been trying it with `i2d_RSA_PUBKEY_fp` and `d2i_RSA_PUBKEY_fp` but to no avail - only segmentation faults.

The difference between *_RSA_PUBKEY* and *_RSAPublicKey* seems to be that the former uses a SubjectPublicKeyInfo (certificate public key) structure  and the latter uses a PKCS#1 RSAPublicKey structure.

Comment: d2i_RSA_PUBKEY_fp is the equivalent function for reading DER. If you're seeing seg faults from it then perhaps you'd like to share the problematic code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *d2i_** function family is available for converting DER to openssl internal datastructures.

So, you should be able to use:

```
FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
RSA *rsa_key = d2i_RSAPublicKey_fp(fp, NULL);
int keylength = RSA_size(rsa_key);
```

to achieve what you want.

Comment: Note: `d2i_RSAPublicKey_fp` is an OpenSSL 1.1.0 and later API. If you're still on OpenSSL 1.0.2 (most likely because of FIPS compliance) that API is not available and you'll have to roll your own.

Comment: This was absolutely useful and concise, thank you @Ctx. Additional info for somebody who might use this solution and still gets segementation faults: try to initialize your RSA struct with NULL and not only declare it without initialization.